# Array contains data from mongodb's field is not working properly for comparison of values

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to compare elements of an array to the array of values I've fetched from mongodb's field of collection. Below code is working fine for other arrays except those arrays which contain values fetched from database.

> Here Code is working

```
let array1=["a","b", "c", "d"];
                    let array2=[ "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
                    var stringArray2= array2.toString();
                     let finalArray=[];
                     var pos=0;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= array1.length; i++) {                             
                        const current_appID=array1[i-1].toString();
                        if(stringArray2.indexOf(current_appID) > -1) {
                            //console.log(current_appID);
                        }
                         else
                        {
                           finalArray[pos]=current_appID;
                           pos++;


                        }
                    }
                    console.log("StringArray2 does not contain b below substr/array elements");
                    console.log(finalArray);
```

> Output

[image]

> Here code is not working properly

```
console.log(db_arr);
                    //et array1=["a","b", "c", "d"];
                    //let array2=[ "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
                    //var stringArray2= array2.toString();

                    const dbArryaString= db_arr.toString();   //db_arr is array fetched from database     //297 elements                 
                     let finalArray=[];
                     var pos=0;
                    for (var i = 1; i <= resulted_ids.length; i++) {     // resulted_ids is random array //300 elements                       
                        const current_appID=resulted_ids[i-1].toString();
                        if(dbArryaString.indexOf(current_appID) > -1) {
                            //console.log(current_appID);
                        }
                         else
                        {
                           finalArray[pos]=current_appID;
                           console.log(finalArray[pos]);
                           pos++;


                        }
                    }
                    console.log("StringArray2 does not contain below substr/array elements");
                    console.log(finalArray);
```

> Output

[image]

> Desired output : (because db_arr(dbArryaString) doesn't contain these elements of resulted_ids(array) )

[image]

Comment: How does `resulted_ids` array looks like?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it would always be better to try to avoid reinventing the wheel.

I suggest you use lodash's `difference` to perform this. It will save you the hassle and make your code cleaner.

(fist of all `npm install --save lodash`)

```js
import {difference} from 'lodash';

let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
let array2 = ["c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
let finalArray = difference(array1, array2)
```